# TCP Client/Server communication only sends first message?

Tags: java, android, tcp

I am setting up a simple TCP Client Server interaction in java.

### **Server:**

The server is a desktop client written in Java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class TCPServer
{
    public static int PORT_NUMBER = 6129;

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
        String clientMessage;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);

        while (true)
        {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            clientMessage = inFromClient.readLine();

            System.out.println("Received: " + clientMessage);

            outToClient.writeBytes("I received this: "+ clientMessage +"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

---

### **Client:**

The client is an android app that connects to the server with TCP. In the client I have a method `sendMessage(String msg)` which attempts to send a message to the server.

```
public static void sendMessage(String msg) throws IOException
{
    if (mainSocket == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!mainSocket.isConnected())
    {
        connectSocket();
    }
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter( mainSocket.getOutputStream());
    output.println(msg);
    output.flush();
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

The problem is, the server receives the first message, but any subsequent messages won't show up at all. When I close the client down, all of a sudden all the other messages show up at once in the server.

This is what the server sees:

```
Received: message 1
```

No activity for a long time...
Then I shut down the client

```
Received: message 2 message 3 message 4 message 5 etc..
```

I put a println in the sendMessage() method, and the method itself is being called in real time.

Comment: From what context is the `sendMessage` method run? Is it from an `Activity` running on the UI thread, or from some class running on a non-ui thread?

Comment: sendMessage is called from an onKeyUp event in an Activity within the main UI Thread. Does this need to be in its own thread?

Comment: I had a similar issue that was caused by bad threading, but the answer seems to be the correct one ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly `close()` your `PrintWriter` on the client side each time you send a message. Same on the server side when you are done reading `inFromClient`, and again when you are done writing to `outToClient`.

See also this [basic example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html), they explain the basic workflow quite nicely:

> However, the basics are much the same as they are in this program:
>
> Open a socket.
>
> Open an input stream and output stream to the socket.
>
> Read from and write to the stream according to the server's protocol.
>
> Close the streams.
>
> Close the socket.

Comment: Awesome. I did an explicit call to close() on the PrintWriter and socket and it works now. I didn't realize that close() isn't implicitly called automatically. Thanks!

Comment: @Razor Storm This answer is not correct. You need to *flush* the PrintWriter every time you send a message, and close it when the conversation is complete. Closing it after every message forces a new connection per message, which is pretty extravagant.

Comment: Ok, in my original code, I had a `flush()` after each sendMessage and no close on either printWriter nor socket, but it was exhibiting the problem I described. Do you know of any other reason this might be?

Comment: As it looks you flushed only the client side. But you also have to flush on the server side. EJP is right that re-opening a new connection for every message is not the most elegant way, but it's one that works nevertheless. You could also try leaving the connection open, flushing on both sides each time a particular message is "completed".

Comment: It seems that the way my server is written it was designed to take one message per connection. I put an inner loop in the infinite while loop that goes `while(connectionSocket.isConnected()){//listen for message}`. When the socket is not connected anymore, it will go back to listening mode.